How to switch a Sharepoint List connection in a Form in Power Apps to another without ruining the cards
I have a form in power apps linked to a list. I made copies of both and wanted to conect this copies. But when I change the link in the copied form to the copied list, all the cards in the form get back to default settings.
What could be the problem?
Thanks.
Conecté la nueva lista a la nueva aplicación/formulario y todas las tarjetas volvieron a la configuración predeterminada. Esperaba que nada cambiara.
